# WAS role AD group mapping reseting after each deployment

Tags: websphere

I have the following security configuration in my web.xml. I am using IBM WAS and opted for AD Authentication for my app. As part of AD configuration I have Mapped the TEST role to an AD Group. Now each time i do a deployment, the mapping is vanishing. Is there way to persist the mapping?

```
<security-role>
        <description>Test</description>
        <role-name>TEST</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/rock/index.html</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>TEST</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/rock/signon/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/rock/signon/login.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

Comment: How are you doing deployment? Bindings should stay ok if you do application update, not uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Yes I do uninstall and install.. Anyway it's resolved now.. I did this in two ways. One by adding ibm-application-bnd.xml to the ear file.. The other we can do a WAS level script configuration..

Comment: Yes, these are good, valid options. Add it as an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

1. using `ibm-application-bnd.xml` and `application.xml` in `ear/META-INF`
2. configuring the WAS script to make the changes.

I have not explored the second option, but i resolved the deployment problem using the first approach

**ibm-application-bnd.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_2.xsd"
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    version="1.2">

    <security-role name="ROLE"> 
        <group name="LDAP GROUP" />
    </security-role>

</application-bnd>
```

**application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>rest-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>rest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/rest</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>ROLE</role-name>
  </security-role>
</application>
```